# Netlify + Nuxt - Remove trailing slash

Tags: redirect, url-routing, nuxt.js, netlify

I am generating static pages from nuxt on netlify. We have the structure of url without trailing slashes. 
For SSR we had trailingslash option set to false and custom redirect with redirect module. But for 'nuxt generate' option this is no longer working

I can't seem to setup 301 redirects for url's  ending with trailing slash.

Eg.
https://example.com/blog  - works
https://example.com/blog/ - throws 404

in nuxt.config we got

```
router: {
  trailingSlash: false
},

redirect: [{
  from: '^/(.*)/$',
  to: (from, req) => {
  let trailingUrl = req.url.endsWith('/') ? req.url.slice(0, -1) : req.url
  return trailingUrl
},
statusCode: 301
}],
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The trailing slash is actually more correct than without. Removing the slash is done by browsers (for reasons I don't recall).

Comment: @Rob thanks for your answer. I know. But the structure we got now is without trailingslash and the links are like that in google. SO we don't want to mess up with SEO at this stage and leve the redirects as they are